# Why is having `scroll-behavior: smooth` both in the html element and its descendant broken in Chromium based browsers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, chromium

I came across a weird issue that's present on my page when viewing on Chromium based browsers (i.e. Google Chrome, Opera, Edge etc.) both on desktop and mobile. I had HTML navigation bookmarks to sections on the page. Within each section there was a horizontally scrolling photo gallery (flex-container) with HTML navigation bookmarks to each photo inside the gallery container. I set `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to both the `html` element and the flex-container in order for the page to scroll smoothly both vertically (whole page) and horizontally (within each flex-container).

This caused the HTML bookmarks to not scroll the gallery horizontally at all (except for when the viewport wasn't level with the flex-container). This issue was not present in Firefox or Safari.

Below is a minimal example of the unusual behaviour:

```css
html {
  /* having `scroll-behavior: smooth;` here BRAKES THE CODE! */
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


.wrapper {
  /* dummy height to simulate further content */
  height: 200vh;
}

.container {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container img {
  /* making images fit nicely in flex-container */
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1 class="logo-text">This is the page title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1" id="img1-1">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/2" id="img1-2">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/3" id="img1-3">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/4" id="img1-4">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/5" id="img1-5">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/7" id="img1-6">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/8" id="img1-7">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/9" id="img1-8">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/10" id="img1-9">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/11" id="img1-10">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/12" id="img1-11">
    </div>
    <nav class="container-nav">
      <ol>
        <li><a href=#img1-1>Photo 1</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-2>Photo 2</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-3>Photo 3</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-4>Photo 4</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-5>Photo 5</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-6>Photo 6</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-7>Photo 7</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-8>Photo 8</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-9>Photo 9</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-10>Photo 10</i></a></li>
        <li><a href=#img1-11>Photo 11</i></a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Removing `scroll-behavior: smooth;` from the html element fixed the issue, however, I wanted smooth scrolling both on the html element and the flex-container. I was able to work around the issue using JavaScript, by dynamically adding and removing the `scroll-behavior: smooth;` on the html element, depending on what type of hyperlink was clicked.

I am curious as to whether this is just a bug in the Chromium browsers, or am I doing something wrong, not understanding how a certain aspect works?

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so if there is anything I can improve or state more clearly please do let me know.

Comment: do you mean GC running under chrome OS or GC anywhere ? (GC + win10 = no scroll bug)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Just tested it out. It turns out that the above code works absolutely fine (no bug) through StackOverflow's "Run Code Snippet". In CodePen it works fine too. However when running the code from a local file or from my server on Google Chrome (or any of the other browsers mentioned), the problem persists on Windows, Linux and Android (the OSs I've tested).

Comment: okay, do you have a github account or any other free hosting to check this live ? I'm curious now :)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Of course, here is the [live page on GitHub](https://dawidl022.github.io/so-question-1-scroll-bug/)

Comment: Hello, hmm , looks like it deserve to be seen as a real bug . It probably already stands there https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=scroll-behavior  I understand and see how annoying it is. (my english is not rich enough to word that bug and find if it was already submitted)